# How to execute a php function with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This is the script that will post the result to the clearCartFunction.php page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#deleteButton").click(function(){
        var result = confirm('Are you sure?');
        if(result){
            $.post("clearCartFunction.php",{confirmation: result}, 
                function(status){
                    alert(status);
                });
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

There is a button on my website

```
 <button type="submit" name="clearCart" value="clear" id="deleteButton">Clear Cart</button>
```

When I click on this button it should execute the function but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<?php
session_start();

function clearCart(){
    $_SESSION['finalCart']=array();
    $_SESSION['cart']=array();
}

if (isset($_POST['confirmation'])){
    clearCart(); 
}
?>
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Is it calling the PHP? Check the Apache logs to see if the script is run?

Comment: If its calling the PHP then check the content of `$_POST`

Comment: Oh okay I realized what was the issue. Basically the code was working but since cart is an array, I needed to refresh the page for it to happen. So I just had to add a location.reload().

Answer (score 0):

use postman software and test that php file by sending it request .see whether it works itself or not.maybe that JQ function is not flawless .

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify what exactly is wrong with your code I'm going to take a guess and provide you with two options:

1. **Dump $_POST['confirmation'] to make sure it's not actually empty**

   ```
   echo '<pre>';
   echo die(var_dump($_POST['confirmation']));
   echo '</pre>';
   ```
2. **Try adding exit() at the end of the script**

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['confirmation'])){
     clearCart(); 
     exit();
   }
   ```

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to include what was wrong. So the code just does not do the intended thing which was to clear the cart.

Answer (score -1):

Oh okay I realized what was the issue. Basically the code was working but since cart is an array, I needed to refresh the page for it to happen. So I just had to add a location.reload()